# Bundle ActivSync 4.5 With Visual Studio 2005 Setup Project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2005, installation

How do you bundle ActivSync with your C#.NET application? I have an installer and it works fine for the SQL Server 2005 Express and .NET 2.0 Framework when I selected them as prerequisites. I'd also like to setup ActivSync as a pre-requisite as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want ActiveSync to appear in your Visual Studio setup project's list of available prerequisites then you will need to create a custom bootstrapper package.  Here is a very thorough blog post on the subject:

http://nikolkos.blogspot.com/2008/09/activesync-45-bootstrapper.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using the install shield IDE to make the setup and bundle the active sync with that